# Android emulator won't mount SD card

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm running a virtual machine in Android Studio. The problem is that it is never mounting the SD card. 
In the settings, I've tried studio-managed (100MB) as well as creating one by myself:

```
$ ./mksdcard -l sdCard 100M sdcard.img
```

The file is in my home folder with R/W rights.

This is my configuration:

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
AvdId=DEVICEC_API_17
PlayStore.enabled=false
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=DEVICEC API 17
disk.dataPartition.size=800M
hw.accelerometer=no
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=emulated
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.cpu.ncore=4
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.manufacturer=User
hw.device.name=DEVICEC
hw.gps=no
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.initialOrientation=landscape
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=no
hw.sensors.proximity=no
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-17/google_apis/x86/
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
sdcard.path=/home/user/sdcard.img
showDeviceFrame=no
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=800x600
skin.path=_no_skin
skin.path.backup=_no_skin
tag.display=Google APIs
tag.id=google_apis
vm.heapSize=48
```

As you can see, `hw.sdCard` is set to `YES`.

Honestly I don't know what to look for in Logcat. Filtering MOUNT I saw this:

```
08-14 17:45:55.544 1495-1508/system_process I/SystemServer: Mount Service
08-14 17:45:55.544 1495-1508/system_process D/MountService: got storage path: /mnt/sdcard description: USB storage primary: true removable: false emulated: false mtpReserve: 0 allowMassStorage: false maxFileSize: 0
08-14 17:45:55.544 1495-1508/system_process D/MountService: addVolumeLocked() StorageVolume [mStorageId=0 mPath=/mnt/sdcard mDescriptionId=17040615 mPrimary=true mRemovable=false mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 mAllowMassStorage=false mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null]
08-14 17:45:55.554 1495-1533/system_process D/MountService: volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (null -> removed)
08-14 17:45:55.554 1495-1533/system_process W/MountService: getSecureContainerList() called when storage not mounted
```

I've also tried running this in the command line:

```
$ ./emulator -avd CASIO_API_17 -sdcard /home/mariano/sdcard.img
```

But I don't see any error. The SD card just won't mount.

Comment: you should add firstly the write external permision

Comment: change image volume label from sdCard something else.

Comment: >you should add firstly the write external permision
To what?

>change image volume label from sdCard something else.
what image volume?

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be an issue with the recent emulator version, possibly in relation with older Android versions (Jelly Bean, etc.).

Downgrading the SDK tools to a previous version solves the issue.

It works for example with r25.2.5, which you can download for [Windows](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip), [Linux](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip), or [Mac OS X](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip). 
If you store the tools outside of the original SDK directory you may need to set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable.

Then use the emulator executable shipped with this package to start your AVD:

```
$ ./emulator -avd CASIO_API_17 -sdcard /home/mariano/sdcard.img
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. Extract the downloaded 25.2.5 tools archive for your system above to your sdk directory - I put mine under `C:\Android\sdk\tools-25.2.5\ `. Didn't need to mess with any environment variables, just start the emulator via command-line. If your `config.ini` for the emulator is set up correctly, you shouldn't need to provide any options other than `-avd AVD_NAME`. Hopefully they get the current emulator version fixed soon.

Comment: this answer is very useful, also the comment by @InsanityOnABun is very useful and working without any negative impacts.