# Android emulator does not mount external SD card

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdcard, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to run freshly built Android image on emulator (generic `aosp_x86-eng` target built from current `master` using Google sources). The emulator seems to be working fine, except it does not mount external SD card when run with `-sdcard` option. Emulator version is the one that comes from the git. Everything is executed on a headless server.

My complete list of steps:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86-eng
make -j16
mksdcard 1G sd.img
emulator -no-window -no-skin -no-audio -sdcard sd.img &
adb shell mount | grep vfat
```

The virtual device appears to be correctly forwarded, as seen by the output of `adb shell blkid`:

```
/dev/block/vda1: LABEL="system" UUID="da594c53-9beb-f85c-85c5-cedf76546f7a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/vdb: LABEL="cache" UUID="f73de97f-7017-ca5e-9b47-ca9c8f633e83" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/vde1: LABEL="vendor" UUID="6d16bab1-58d9-3c5d-8f14-f608f924affd" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/vdf: LABEL="SDCARD" UUID="1CEA-0B06" TYPE="vfat"
```

However, it is not mounted by `vold`. What could be the problem?

I also get the same result when I run emulator using Android 8 image downloaded via SDK manager. With Android 7, SD card works OK.

**EDIT:**

Solved the issue for emulator that comes with aosp_x86-eng build (see my own answer). On the emulator from Android SDK, the cause is probably different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator won't mount SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681272/android-emulator-wont-mount-sd-card)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45967319/929560

Comment: @InsanityOnABun nope, my case is different. But I already solved it. I will post an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, in my case headless mode was the culprit. When I run emulator with `-no-skin -no-window` options, SD card is not mounted. If I remove these options (and enable X11 forwarding, since I work on a headless server), everything works correctly.

I still want to know why I can't use SD card in headless mode, but at least I was able to solve the problem for the required task.

Comment: That's unbelievable. I would have never figured it out otherwise.